# Join two queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Is there a way to join this two queries into one?

```
query = "select foo from TABLE where foo like '%foo%'";

if (query.empty())
    query = "select bar from TABLE where bar like '%foo%'"
```

**Update:**

```
select ifnull(foo,bar) from TABLE where foo like 'foo%' or bar like '%foo%';
```

Thanks to [Kamal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874499/kamal) for the idea

Comment: by if (query.empty()) you mean the result of the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Oracle

Select NVL(foo,bar) from TABLE where foo like '%foo%' or bar like '%foo%';

Answer (score 5):

#### Edited

I just realised that this can return *multiple* rows - here's the fix:

```
select foo from TABLE where foo like '%foo%'
union all
select bar from TABLE where bar like '%foo%'
and not exists (select 'x' from TABLE where foo like '%foo%')
```

Using `UNION ALL` (not `UNION`) will be faster, because `UNION` *sorts* the results.

#### Edited

A request has been made for a non-union solution. I don't have one.

Comment: Why is there a `X` in the query?

Comment: @Bohemian, thx for the one, but tell is there way without `union`?

Comment: I may be interpreting this wrong but as I understood he only wants the second query if the first is null, so there is no need to run 3 selects as you did.

Comment: @Duglas Thx for noticing the typo - fixed it.

Comment: @Diego I don't see any way around it the 3 queries

Comment: Hey @Bohemian! take a look at my answer. I didnt get why you are using a union, there is nothing to union here. If the first query return results, he wants only the first, if it doesnt, he wants the second. A simple if would do the trick

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want `bar` returned where `foo` does return record(s), try:

```
select foo from TABLE where foo like '%foo%'
union all
select bar from TABLE
where bar like '%foo%' and 
      not exists (select null from TABLE where foo like '%foo%')
```

Alternatively, a version without a union:

```
select case when foo like '%foo%' then foo else bar end as foobar
where foo like '%foo%' or 
      (bar like '%foo%' and 
       not exists (select null from TABLE where foo like '%foo%'))
```

Comment: +1 for correct solution. But, like @Bohemian, using `union all` will remove duplicates and that might not be wanted right?

Comment: @aF. `union all` does *not* remove duplicates. `union` *does*.

Answer (score 2):

```
   if not exists (select top 1 foo from TABLE where foo like '%foo%')
        select bar as MyColumn from TABLE where bar like '%foo%'
    else
        select foo as MyColumn from TABLE where foo like '%foo%'
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know mysql syntax but
in sql server we use like this :-

```
  IF EXISTS(select foo from TABLE where foo like '%foo%')
    BEGIN 
    select foo from TABLE where foo like '%foo%'
    END
    ELSE
    select bar from TABLE where bar like '%foo%
```

Comment: he wants to join both queries in one. Not correcting the syntax :P

Comment: no, he just want the second if the first doesn't return anything